# Why do my vertices look so big?

Tags: vertices

[image]

How do I get my vertices back to their original size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport

scroll down to see the option, default is 3 pixels.

[image]