# Very thin edge lines in Edit mode

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe, lines

Why are my edge lines very thin in Blender 4.0.1.? Sometimes I can't even select them from a certain angle, and some vertex dots are invisible and I can't select them as well. In the end, I need to rotate my camera a bit or go to the wireframe mode in order to select some verts or edges.

In terms of settings, I didn't touch anything really. Only in the viewport tab, I have Anti Aliasing set to 32 samples and enabled overlay and edit mode settings. If I turn them off, it's even worse. I also have Blender 3.6.5 in which this problem does not exist.

[image]

Comment: Is your question about how to make them thicker? Or is it something else? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258010/why-do-my-vertices-look-so-big/258011#258011

Comment: I bet no, thickness is fine. For some reason I can't select them from certain angles and need to to rotate camera or go to wireframe mode.

Comment: Just checking... is your N panel  View > Clipping range sensible for the scale of the geometry?

Comment: object is aprox 100x100x100 mm, clip start is 1 mm and clip end is 1000 mm